# How to set a simple jQuery hide/show function to show all before hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down selection, once it select it will show the div where the value and class share the same name and hide all else.

How can I have it so before you select it'll show all and only hide after you select a option  ?

**EDIT**
I have updated the code snippet to run, have built in markup however on my local its php.

**Revised question**

how can I adjust my jQuery to show all, when none are selected and the selection is on default.

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function () {
            $j("select").change(function () {
                $j(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
                    var optionValue = $j(this).attr("value");
                    if (optionValue) {
                        $j(".career_div").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                        $j("." + optionValue).show();
                    } else {
                        $j(".career_div").hide();
                    }
                });
            })
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="all">Default</option>
    <option value="one">Intelligence (2)</option>
  <option value="two">Engineering (2)</option>
  <option value="three">Marketing (0)</option>
</select>

<section class="py-3 section-grey">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 one career_div">
        <strong>Intelligence</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 one career_div">
        <strong>Intelligence</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 two career_div">
        <strong>Engineering</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 line-grey two career_div">
        <strong>Engineering</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Given that you call .change() on load, your user will never get to select their own option... unless you also check [`.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

Comment: It's unclear if by *"it will show the option value and hide all else"* applies to the `<select><option></option>` or to the `$("." + optionValue)` - if it's the case of the `$("." + optionValue)` then simply don't call `.change()` at the startup should do what you're after.

Comment: cheers, ill update the question

Comment: You can remove the `..change();` then your page will be in the default state.  If the default state is *not* show all, then add `$(".career_div").show()`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, ill play around with that idea, if not update question with full code

Comment: @freedomn-m i was unable to get it working, so I have created a snippet in my question.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your intended output / start position is meant to be, but how does this look: https://jsfiddle.net/evf7bgdz/

Comment: The alternative (solution) would be: https://jsfiddle.net/evf7bgdz/1/  - but it's a little confusing as your `<option value="one">Engineering</option>` matches divs `.one` that are "Intelligence" - you have your "one" "two" values swapped for the option caption.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I see what you mean, my bad i was just writing quick markup as my local code is php. put the classes wrong war round. the fiddle is perfect. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a couple of changes:

- use `$(this).val()` (this=`select`) to get the `value=` from the select option, no need to find `option:selected` and loop as `.val()` does this for you.
- check for "all" then don't apply the filter
- as noted in the comments, "one"/"two" were around the wrong way (no impact on functionality, just makes it look like it's wrong)

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var opt = $(this).val();
    if (opt === "all") {
      $(".career_div").show();
    } else {
      $(".career_div").hide();
      $("." + opt).show();
    }   
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="all">Default</option>
  <option value="two">Engineering (2)</option>
  <option value="one">Intelligence (2)</option>
  <option value="three">Marketing (0)</option>
</select>

<section class="py-3 section-grey">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 one career_div">
        <strong>Intelligence</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 one career_div">
        <strong>Intelligence</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 two career_div">
        <strong>Engineering</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 line-grey two career_div">
        <strong>Engineering</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```